# Chrome videos are zoomed in

Tags: gnome, google-chrome

I have a problem with Chrome. Everything is fine, but videos seem to be zoomed in and cropped by their bounding boxes. It happens on multiple sites (youtube, 9gag etc.).

On Firefox it works just fine.

I have tried disabling GPU acceleration and running chrome with:

```
--high-dpi-support=1 --force-device-scale-factor=1
```

Chrome version: `74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Does anybody had similar issues? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I seems that my configuration got really screwed up. What finally helped is to completely purge the chrome-stable package **and** completely remove following config directory:

```
/home/USERNAME/.config/google-chrome
```

I hope it helps somebody.